# Having trouble with perms in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions

I am pretty new to linux, so please forgive me if I say anything ignorant. The first of which will probably be this. I need to modify a folder, such that any subsequent files or folders placed within it inherit 777 perms. I understand this is not something that is usually done, however, this is an isolated system running a series of programs to move files around, and to access these files, they need execute perms.

I have tried using ACL's to do it, however, they dont seem to be inheriting the execute rights for some reason. A chmod -R will do it once, but I need to find a way to automate this process.

Any ideas? Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) to watch for files moved into your directory using the `moved_to` event.

You could also use [fsmonitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsmonitor) to run a node process that watches for changes and executes chmod.

Comment: If there no way to add an inherent value to a folder so all files get the same perms without scripting?

Comment: Not that I know of. Most use cases for modifying directory contents on events are done through background processes with _some_ sort of script